# Using SASS varibles from brother file

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a problem while trying to do a very basic thing with sass.

I just have the following file structure:

Styles folder:

```
 └───src
    ├───styles
    │    └───_variables.scss // here I have only a variable
    |    └─── sharedStyles.scss // here are all my vars
    |
    ├─ App.tsx // Where I usee the style
```

The `_variables.scss` has only the following:

`$my-Blue: #04284D;`

And here is my `sharedStyles.scss`

```
@import "variables.scss";

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: $my-blue;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.App-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.App-intro {
  font-size: large;
}
```

When I compile it I always get the same error:

```
"message": "Undefined variable: \"$my-blue\".",
  "formatted": "Error: Undefined variable: \"$my-blue\".\n        on line 8 of src/styles/sharedStyles.scss\n>>   background-color: $my-blue;\n\n
```

I know is pretty basic but I could not understand what's going on here.

Comment: You declared it as `$my-Blue: #04284D` but you used it as `$my-blue`.

Comment: ... which is why variable naming conventions are important. You should never have to try and remember how you cased something.

Comment: thank you so much. That was it.